# addClass to current li element and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to `addClass` of blue to when the **next** current `li` is clicked and `removeClass` of the **previous** `li`. However, I can't seem to get it working, it adds the class to the other li instead, but seems to remove the previous class.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5otouLxg/1/

```
var $li = $("li a#t1:first-child");
var $li2 = $("li a#t2:first-child");
$('li').click(function () {
    if ($li.children().has
```

```js
var $li = $("li a#t1:first-child");
var $li2 = $("li a#t2:first-child");

$('li').click(function () {
    if ($li.children().hasClass('nav-1')) {
        $li.children().addClass('blue');
        $li2.children().removeClass('blue');
    }
    if ($li2.children().hasClass('nav-2')) {
        $li.children().removeClass('blue');
        $li2.children().addClass('blue');
    }
});
```

```css
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a id="t1">
        <span class="nav-1">HELLO</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="t2">
        <span class="nav-2">HELLO</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Does this work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/5otouLxg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by simplifying your code: works with [Two li's](https://jsfiddle.net/5otouLxg/9/) or [A bunch of li's](https://jsfiddle.net/5otouLxg/10/)

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').addClass('blue');
    $(this).siblings().children('a').removeClass('blue');
});
```

Comment: Should be $(this).find('span') to stay consistent with what the original accomplished, otherwise good answer.

Comment: Why does the `span` matter? OP just wanted to find the next `li` according to the description.

Comment: li colors the bullet and text, span only colors text

Answer (score 0):

I've use another script to make it works

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass('blue');
    $(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

The script will remove all 'blue' class of all the li (if more than 2), and add the class to the one that's been clicked.

Hope this is what you need.

[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/5otouLxg/5/)